# Etsy file upload (curl) Err: Request body is too large

Tags: php, curl, etsy

There are few practically the same questions but no good answer.
I have to send images to Etsy endpoint.

Decided to use [lusitanian](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib) library found on git. It internally uses curl to make POST request.

Constantly get "The request body is too large" response.

Code:

```
$data = [
        //'@image' => new \CURLFile($imagePath, $mime, $imageFilename),
        '@image' => '@'.$imagePath.';type='.$mime,
    ];

    try {
        $response = $etsyService->request(
            $this->uri . '/' . $listingId . '/images',
            'POST',
            $data,
            array(
                'Content-Type'=>'multipart/form-data'
        );
        var_dump($response);die;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Internally lusitanian uses this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
```

to make a request. Tried both from above $data.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

var_dump of header (curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);)

```
    array (size=27)
      'url' => string 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/645283994/images' (length=53)
      'content_type' => string 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
      'http_code' => int 400
      'header_size' => int 895
      'request_size' => int 590
      'filetime' => int -1
      'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
      'redirect_count' => int 0
      'total_time' => float 0.234278
      'namelookup_time' => float 3.9E-5
      'connect_time' => float 0.023493
      'pretransfer_time' => float 0.083739
      'size_upload' => float 105
      'size_download' => float 29
      'speed_download' => float 123
      'speed_upload' => float 448
      'download_content_length' => float 29
      'upload_content_length' => float 105
      'starttransfer_time' => float 0.234254
      'redirect_time' => float 0
      'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
      'primary_ip' => string '151.101.13.224' (length=14)
      'certinfo' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'primary_port' => int 443
      'local_ip' => string '192.168.2.73' (length=12)
      'local_port' => int 40466
      'request_header' => string 'POST /v2/listings/645283994/images HTTP/1.1

    Host: openapi.etsy.com

    User-Agent: PHPoAuthLib

    Accept: */*

    Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="**************************", oauth_nonce="****************************8", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1542272124", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_token="*************", oauth_signature="******************"
Content-type: multipart/form-data
Connection: close
Content-Length: 105
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was (as much as I could see) in the lusitanian library.

In Signature class getSignature method, line 62 stands:

```
$signatureData[rawurlencode($key)] = rawurlencode($value);
```

From some reason in this $signatureData are also data from the request body. Because image field is here, which is an object rowurlencode() returned null!

Problem solved (temporary!) with:

```
if(strpos($key, 'oauth_') !== false) {
    $signatureData[rawurlencode($key)] = rawurlencode($value);
}
```

And with commented three lines from curlClient class 91 - 93.

It took me a few days to find out. Mr. President give me the medal :)